# Which site will be useful on Stack Exchange for understanding urdu shayari?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which site will be useful on StackEexchange for understanding urdu shayari by famous shayras like Mirza  Galib sahab and John Elia?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what those are, but there's a hinduism SE that includes hindu philosophy, but if your question is about the hindi language then that's not definitely not on topic here (and I suspect not on topic there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's translated you might get an answer on [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), in original Urdu there is no really fitting site.